# Erlang application: different environment

Tags: erlang

What is the recommended way to have different values for application environment variables in an erlang application?

What I mean here is: how do you support different environment in your application (e.g. development, stage, production) in your erlang application? For example I would like tests using a specific fake service on a known host and production code use the real server on a different host.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use application config file as well. you can also pass the config as parameter while starting an erlang console that can help you in setting up environment variables. so you are pass test.config or production.config based on environment there by no need to compile the code and start them.

You can find more info here

http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/config.html

Answer (score 1):

Dependency injection.

```
test_setup() -> [ {host,"http://..."}, ... ].
prod_setup() -> [ {host,"http://..."}, ... ].

test_start() -> start(test_setup()).
prod_start() -> start(prod_setup()).

start(Config) -> ... .
```

Alternately, policy modules.  Make a policy whose interface matches the stuff you need, then pass in the name of the module containing the policy you want.  Think ETS/DETS.